# Login Script to pull users telephoneNumber from AD and then create a registry key in HKCU with that value

Tags: vbscript, registry, login-script

I am trying to create a login script that pulls the logged in users telephone extension from active directory, I then want to take that variable and use it to create a registry string value in HKCU\software\ with that extension number.

I can create registry keys, and pull the data from AD, but I am stumped on how to pass the information from AD to my registry entry.

Example extension is **1234** and I want to create a registry value of `HKCU\software\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client\AgentID, "1234"`

Thanks for any help!

**Script 1**

```
Dim objSysInfo, objUser
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
set strtelno = objuser.telephonenumber ' Currently logged in User
```

**Script 2**

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client\"
KeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client"
strValueName = "AgentID"
strValue = "1234"
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strvaluename, strvalue
```

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, and we might be able to help.  SO is not here to write your entire script for you.

Comment: Basically what I have so far are two scripts.  One that pulls from AD and the other to create the reg key 
    
Dim objSysInfo, objUser
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
set strtelno = objuser.telephonenumber
' Currently logged in User
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)

Comment: Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
 
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
 
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client\"
KeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client"
strValueName = "AgentID"
strValue = "1234"
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strvaluename, strvalue

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out how to tie the two scripts together, maybe I just haven't had enough coffee yet :)

Comment: vbsedit has a good collection of scripts for this. 
http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/ad/users/list/scr_151.asp
http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/registry/scr_999.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of it, you are very close. Try (untested code):

```
Dim objSysInfo, objUser
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
set strtelno = objuser.telephonenumber ' Currently logged in User

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client\"
KeyPath = "SOFTWARE\shoreline teleworks\shoreware client"
strValueName = "AgentID"
strValue = strtelno ' <-- This sets the Telephone Number
objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strvaluename, strvalue
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I had to do a little tweaking to what you suggested but I got it working!  You are a life saver, now I don't have to touch 200+ pcs.  :)